# Num type class operations in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to write an interpreter in Haskell (to be precise, I'm following the book Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours). I try to add float arithmetic to the interpreter. Now I have the following code:

```
data LispVal = Number Integer
             | Float Float
             deriving(Show, Eq)

doNumeric :: (Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> LispVal -> LispVal -> LispVal
doNumeric op (Number a) (Number b) = Number $ a `op` b
doNumeric op (Float a) (Number b) = Float $ a `op` (fromIntegral b)
doNumeric op (Number a) (Float b) = Float $ (fromIntegral a) `op` b
doNumeric op (Float a) (Float b) = Float $ a `op` b
```

In this way, I hope to construct numeric operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division simply by means like: doNumeric (+), doNumeric (-).. etc. so that I do not need to write code for doMul, doAdd etc.

But regarding the code above, GHC complains that:

```
Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Float'
Expected type: a
  Actual type: Float
In the first argument of `op', namely `a'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `a `op` (fromIntegral b)'
In the expression: Float $ a `op` (fromIntegral b)
```

So if I want op to take an operation that is present in Num type class, what should I do? How can I make the above code typecheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to apply a function `op` with type `a -> a -> a` to a *specific* type. What your signature says is "`op` is a binary operator on a *specific* type `a`". That is, `a` is determined by the function that is passed in, and it may not be `Integer` or `Float`. (It's a bit odd that GHC gives you the warning on the second definition, but if you comment out the last three, you'll see it also gives it when you just define `doNumeric` for two `Number`s.)

The way you are using `op`, you really need a rank 2 type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

doNumeric :: (forall a . (Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> LispVal -> LispVal -> LispVal
doNumeric op (Number a) (Number b) = Number $ a `op` b
...
```

What this means is that `op` is guaranteed to work for *any* `Num` type `a`, which I suspect is what you are going for. Hence you can call `doNumeric` with `(+)`, but not with `f :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: Great! Solved my problem. BTW, could you please share your way in Haskell starting from novice? I can hardly find materials that covers such aspect and frustration do grow from time to time. Thanks!